# Regex - Words with 2 different letters repeated twice followed by a number repeated 6 times

Tags: regex

I need to regex that matches a string like **LLMM222222**. I tried with pattern like `(\w{2})(\w{2})2{6}` but it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex with 2 back-references:

```
^([A-Za-z])\1([A-Za-z])\2(\d)\3{5}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/psS16e/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `([A-Za-z])`: Match a letter and capture it in group #1
- `\1`: Make sure we repeat same letter using a back-reference #1
- `([A-Za-z])`: Match a letter and capture it in group #2
- `\1`: Make sure we repeat same letter using a back-reference #2
- `\d`: Match and capture a digit in capture group #3
- `\3{5}`: Make sure we repeat same digit 5 more times using a back-reference #3
- `$`: End